# what is wrong with this PriorityQueue?

Tags: java

```
fringe = new PriorityQueue<Node>(10,new Comparator<Node>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Node node1,Node node2)
            {
                if (f(node1)>f(node2))
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        });
```

I declared a PQ to store some nodes and i want to store the nodes in non-decreasing order according to the f value.function f(Node node) is to calculate the f value for the node. so i override the comparator but right now i found that some nodes with larger f value are placed before the ones with smaller f value in the queue, i checked all over but still cannot find what goes wrong, i assume maybe it is the PQ declaration's problem. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it "Out of order" when you iteratively pop out elements out of it? or only on construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @izomorphius, PriorityQueue does not guarantee full ordering, only that the head is always minimal.

If you want full order - you might want to chose one of these possiblities:

1. Use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - but note it will not allow duplicates. Also, as stated by @JoonasPulakka, here you will probably want to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` as well.
2. Use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - populate it [unordered] and then use [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort it according to your comparator
3. use an array [`Node[]`], populate it [unordered] and then use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort it according to your comparator.

**EDIT:**

Your editted Comparator does not enforce full ordering, and thus the result of using it is undefined:

let `a`,`b` be two `Node`s such that `f(a) == f(b)`

```
compare(a,b) == compare(b,a) == -1
```

But the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) states:

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y,
>   x)) for all x and y.

Thus, the result of using this [the editted] comparator is undefined.

**EDIT2:**

Your comments suggest you are looking for a second criteria - of "adding time". You can add another field `long timestamp` to your `Node` object, and in your `Comparator` return a result based on this field if and only if `f(node1) == f(node2)`. This will guarantee consistency, and will achieve the wanted feature.

Note: this field will be initialized once [and only once!] when you add an element to the queue for the first time [or when the object is created, if it's an option].

Comment: say if there is already a node which has f value 5 in PQ, now i want to enqueue another node which has 5 as well, this new node will be added right after the old one by default, but what i want is to put it in front fo the old one. your method seems cant deal with this

Comment: @tonyaziten: Put a second `timestamp`, based on [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), and if the `f()` of two objects is evaluated to be the same, compare according to the `timestamp` criteria. I don't understand why won't it do exactly what you want, I am probably misunderstanding you.

Comment: i try to implement the second criteria as you suggest, but it seems a lot of node got same timestamp, is it possilbe?

Comment: @tonyaziten: if millis is not sensitive enough, you might want to use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). Important: read the doce: `This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time`, so you'll need to take `nanTime()-baseLine`, where `baseLine` was initialized with `nanoTime()` before you start inserting elements.

Comment: nice!nanoTime works, i did not initialize baseline but just replace System.currentTimeMillis() with System.nanoTime() and it works! although the code does not look that elegant, so far i cannot figure out any other ways besides yours.Probably implementing my own PQ is an alternative. Thanks amit!

Answer (score 6):

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). I quote:

`The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the PriorityQueue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).`

All that is guaranteed is that the top element is the minimum one according to the Comparator.

Comment: I did't use Iterator to traverse the queue, in my program i just used a for loop to print out the f value of each node in the queue. does it work the same as Iterator?

Comment: It uses iterator internally. As I said only thing that is guaranteed is that the top is the smallest element. So what you can do is to do a loop where you do peek and then poll until there are elements in the queue. When you do that you will see that you peek the elements in order.

Comment: @tonyaziten note that in this case, even the top element isn't guaranteed, since your comparator does not comply with the requirements stated in the javadocs. Note that if the comparator is "correct" you are expected to see the "right" order only if you iteratively take the head of the priority queue out and print it.

Comment: @amit in fact his code has changed and I believe the first version of the comparator did comply.

Comment: @izomorphius: I know, I voted-up this answer for that exact reason, but nevertheless, I found it important to let the OP know about his fault.

Comment: @amit@izomorphius the reason why i write compare() like this is because if the f value of 2 nodes are the same, i wanna put the last added node in front of the old node, but like you guys said this version does not comply to javadoc requirement, i need to figure out another way to achieve this...

Comment: @tonyaziten: You can use a second criteria to achieve this, I explained this idea in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also override `equals()`? As pointed out in [Comparator docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html),

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

Also note that when you override `equals()`, you also have to override `hashCode()`, as pointed out in [Object docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Even though `PriorityQueue` is not a (sorted) set, as pointed in comments, if you want to switch your data structure something that can be iterated in particular order (queue can't, sorted set can), then it's better to have `compare()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()` implemented exactly as recommended.

Comment: As far as I remember, the `PriorityQueue` does not use `equals()`, and it is not a `Set`. Could you point to a documentation that talks about `PriorityQueue`s?

Comment: from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29): `It is generally the case, but **not strictly required** that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y)).`

Comment: @amit: Not required, but certainly recommended: `Generally speaking, any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact.` Particularly, if you happen to switch your data structure from something that doesn't strictly require consistent equals & compare, to something that *does* require it, you'll appreciate that your data items already do the recommended thing. It's the same thing with `equals()` and `hashCode()`: in many cases,  everything works ok by overriding only one of them, but it'll bite you later on.

Comment: I'd agree if that was the natural order comparing - the `compareTo()` method, which is inherited from a [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), but for a custom-comparator, it is often not the case. In any case, that does not explains why his elements are out of order.